# Adding elements to BST causes an error

Tags: python

I have implemented BST using python but there are some errors coming when adding elements to the tree

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,word,meaning):
        self.left=None
        self.right=None
        self.word=word
        self.meaning=meaning



class BST:
    def __init__(self,word,meaning):
        self.root=Node(word,meaning)

    def add_word(self,word,meaning):
        if(self.root.word==None):
            self.root.word=word
            self.root.meaning=meaning
            return "Create root"

        else:
            current=self.root
            while(1):
                if(word<current.word):
                    if(current.left):
                        self.add_word(word,meaning)
                    else:
                        current.left=Node(word,meaning)
                        break
                elif(word>current.word):
                    if(current.right):
                        self.add_word(word,meaning)
                    else:
                        current.right=Node(word,meaning)
                        break
                else:
                    break

    def in_order(self,node):
        if(node!=None):
            self.in_order(node.root.left)
            print(node.root.word,node.root.meaning)
            self.in_order(node.root.right)
```

Comment: You are using iteration and recursion at the same time. Choose one or the other

Comment: when i removing the while loop there are a run time error comming

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?  (you have to remove the break statements too)

Comment: i have remove break statement too

Comment: When doing recursion, you are always doing this `current=self.root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this one?

```
def add_word(self, word, meaning):
    self._add_word(self.root, word, meaning)
```

def _add_word(self, node, word, meaning):
    if node is None:
        node = Node(word, meaning)
        return
    if word < node.word: self._add_word(node.left, word, meaning)
    elif word > node.word: self._add_word(node.right, word, meaning)

Answer (score 0):

Your `add_word` method doesn't work as a recursive function, since it doesn't have any argument to indicate what node it should operate on. When you call `self.add_word` from within `add_word` (with unmodified arguments) it runs up to the recursion limit.

Instead of doing the recursion, just change the value of `current`:

```
def add_word(self,word,meaning):
    if(self.root.word==None):
        self.root.word=word
        self.root.meaning=meaning
        return "Create root"

    else:
        current=self.root
        while(1):
            if(word<current.word):
                if(current.left):
                    current = current.left # changed here!
                else:
                    current.left = Node(word,meaning)
                    break
            elif(word>current.word):
                if(current.right):
                    current = current.right # and here too!
                else:
                    current.right = Node(word,meaning)
                    break
            else:     # you might want to raise an exception or something here
                break # since this branch indicates that the word alread exists
```

There's also an issue with your `in_order` method, which expects a `node` value, but tries to access a `root` attribute on it (which won't work if `node` is a `Node` instance). The only object with a `root` attribute is the BST itself, so you just want `node.left`, `node.right`, etc.

To get the recursion started, you should make the `node` argument optional, with a default value that is a sentinel, then set `node` to `self.root` if you get the sentinel in the function:

```
_sentinel = object()
def in_order(self, node=_sentinel):
    if(node is not None):
        if node == BST._sentinel:
            node = self.root
        self.in_order(node.left)
        print(node.word, node.meaning)
        self.in_order(node.right)
```

Comment: what do u mean by change the value of current

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that, @Kasunlakmal. Have you looked at the spots in the code where I commented that I'd changed things? By assigning to `current`, the loop makes sense, as each iteration either moves the `current` reference up the tree, or adds a new leaf node and `break`s.